# Get from api react with useState, useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner.
I have such a fetch

```
const getMovieByDecade = (decade) => {
    return api.get(`movie/years/${decade}`)
}
```

API for **${decade}** ex.1920 :

```
 "id": "aebfdffa-748d-4e33-bf2c-da353b185aac",
"title": "Some Movie ",
"year": 1925,
```

How can I download and return movies from this Api sequentially by decade using React Hooks (useState, UseEffetct) ?

```
export const YearOfProduction = () => {

return (
    <HomeWrapper>
        <BackButton />
        <YearOfProductionHeader>
            <h1>Year YearOfProduction</h1>
            <img className="clock" src="/images/clock.png"></img>
        </YearOfProductionHeader>
        <YearsOfProductionWrapper>
            <div className="XIXcentury">
                <span className="century">XIX</span>
                <Years>'90</Years>
            </div>
            <div class="XXcentury">
                <span className="century">XX</span>
                <div className="ten_years">
                    <Years >'00</Years>
                    <Years>'10</Years>
                    <Years>'20</Years>
                    <Years>'30</Years>
                    <Years>'40</Years>
                </div>
                <div className="ten_years">
                    <Years>'50</Years>
                    <Years>'60</Years>
                    <Years>'70</Years>
                    <Years>'80</Years>
                    <Years>'90</Years>
                </div>
            </div>
        </YearsOfProductionWrapper>
      // here I is place for movie list after decades after Click Years

    </HomeWrapper>


)
```

}

Comment: do you want to try using swr? https://swr.vercel.app/#overview . with it you dont need to useEffect on most of the cases.

Comment: Can you please put the code as well you have?

Comment: Yes, add the code of the component for which it needs help

Comment: @Free Do you want to get the data for a year on selection or for a array range all at a time?

Comment: I want get for all

Answer (score -2):

Supposing that you have a form or selector, where the user selects a decade and you fetch movies for the decade, this should work :

```js
const [decade, setDecade] = useState(1990)
const [movies, setMovies] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {

  const getData = async() => {
    await getMovieByDecade(decade);
    setMovies(movies)
  }
  getData()
}, [decade])
```

Comment: I'm going to have a div's that will start sequentially.

Comment: I wouldn't call the function nor use useEffect in your case. Because a simpler & more standard way is to use a submitHandler function that you'd call when submitting the form (where you select a decade).

Comment: But the question in itself said that the developer wanted to achieve it using  React Hooks..

Comment: @Shubham Shukla You are setting a state with a State  `setMovies(movies)` . This is wrong and its kind of recursive

Comment: It is not, movies is not a dependency of that useEffect